# how to get variable from modulus equation

Tags: python, math

how to get the value of 'x' out of this equation using python ?

```
 5443984100737085739 * x mod 10512797518085747507 = 7873334411288369657
```

I've tried inverse function

```
x=inverse((7873334411288369657/5443984100737085739),10512797518085747507)
```

but it gives me x = 0

Comment: From which module does that `inverse` function come? How much mathematics do you know about modular arithmetic? For example, do you understand the Extended Euclidean Algorithm? I have a routine that quickly answers your question, but I need to know if you can understand the algorithm.

Comment: no i don't understand Extended Euclidean Algorithm but if that solve the problem i can search for it

Comment: If you answer my question about the origin of your `inverse` function I will probably be glad to post my routine.

Comment: i imported it from Crypto.Util.number library

Comment: If your base and your number are not coprime, the inverse does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `inverse` attempt using [Crypto.Util.number](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Util.number-module.html) failed because it solves a slightly different problem. It solves the equation

```
u * x % v = 1
```

Note that the right-hand side is `1`, and you can't change that with your attempted division as a parameter.

Here is my Python routine, which uses [the extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to solve that kind of problem where the right-hand side is not necessarily one:

```
def divideresidues(dividend, divisor, modulus):
    """Divide the dividend by the divisor mod modulus. I.e., return the
    smallest positive integer solution to the equation
    x * divisor % modulus = dividend, assuming dividend and divisor
    are positive and less than modulus.
    """
    r, newr = modulus, divisor
    t, newt = 0, 1
    while newr != 0:
        quotient, remainder = divmod(r, newr)
        r, newr = newr, remainder
        t, newt = newt, t - quotient * newt
    if t < 0:
        t = t + modulus
    quotient, remainder = divmod(dividend, r)
    if remainder:
        raise ValueError('Bad division in divideresidues()')
    return t * quotient % modulus
```

The code that prints your desired value of `x` is

```
print(divideresidues(7873334411288369657, 5443984100737085739, 10512797518085747507))
```

which gives the printout

```
845290633298
```

and this can be checked with

```
x=845290633298
print(5443984100737085739 * x % 10512797518085747507)
```

which gives the desired number

```
7873334411288369657
```